# mysql вывести за месяц

Tags: php, mysql

Как вывести данные за текущий месяц?

```
SELECT * FROM `modx_ms2_orders` 
WHERE `createdon` >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
and user_id='".$modx->user->get('id')."' and status=10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете попробовать через округление текущего месяца:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `modx_ms2_orders` 
WHERE `createdon` = date_format(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y-%m-01')
    and user_id='".$modx->user->get('id')."' 
    and status=10
```

либо:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `modx_ms2_orders` 
WHERE month(`createdon`) = month(CURRENT_DATE)
    and year(`createdon`) = year(CURRENT_DATE)
    and user_id='".$modx->user->get('id')."' 
    and status=10
```